# Windows packet forwarding issue

Tags: windows, windows-7, routes, forwarding, tap

My problem is, I have to simulate something on a WIN7 enterprise desktop platform. Therefore, I have to let WIN7 route/forward data packets (ucast/mcast) coming from another environ on another machine into an emulated net stack behind a **tap device**.

I have no profound Windows background. I am a **experienced** unixoid-/linxoidist. But for my current project I am forced to interact with WIN7. In this context, on WIN7 platform a part of a large integration test framework is running so emigration is **not** fathomable.

[image: problem principle]

What I did so far:

1. Forage half the web - There I learned interacting with win routing and that I have to enable forwarding.
2. Set routing up in win7 with **WIN netsh** -> I can list the entries with netsh show mechanism and acknowledge that routes are set properly
3. Activate forwarding in the HKEY registry - so the Windows stack should be prepared!
4. Send mcast/ucast packets to the win stack and **prove them arriving** -> can trace them with pcap (wireshark) - so those are at the **disposal of the win routing** as I understand
5. Having the emulated stack (app) running behind the tap device -> so the tapdev is active as well
6. **verify** that the arriving packets are **NOT** forwarded on the tapdev -> so the issue is at "win_routing"

What I would like to know:

- Is what I am trying to do principally possible? I mean, is win7 desktop prepared for such a task or would I have to wage several additional Micros. Packages or even have a server version?
- Am I missing something conceptually specific to Windows? In unix, the said would be the principle steps.

Comment: I had some issues with TAP drivers and switched to using Bridging (VMWare player), works fine for MCAST/IGMP. Btw, you may have more luck at http://serverfault.com .

Comment: solved it by hacking a virtual napt in python. Works, but is awful somehow!